# Sharepoint: Add an item to a list in a subfolder using webservices

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have a list, that has a custom content type, the list also contains subfolders

How can I add an item to the list using web services, in a specific sub folder?

Comment: Looks difficult
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sharepoint.windowsservices.development/browse_thread/thread/e6e9dc80a4d9ec74/bf15d08c737292eb?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=Using+the+lists+web+service+to+add+list+items+to+folders+in+a+list#bf15d08c737292eb
At a guess I would look at setting something like FileLeafRef

Answer (score 0):

Dim MyQuery As New SPQuery()

MyQuery.Query = Query   ' Set Query

MyQuery.ViewFields = ViewFields   ' Set ViewFields

MyQuery.RowLimit = 0

MyQuery.ViewAttributes = "BaseViewID=""1"" Scope=""Recursive"""

MyQuery.Folder = Folder   ' Set subfolder of list

MyQuery.Query = Query   ' Set Query

Dim MyItemCollection As SPListItemCollection = List.GetItems(MyQuery)